# DbContext.Database.SqlQuery vs ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I've been googling this for a bit but I haven't found anything useful regarding the differences between `DbContext.SqlQuery` vs `ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction`. I'm currently using `.SqlQuery` but my colleague is using `.ExecuteFunction`, so got curious as to why would one be used over the other.

Are there any advantages/disadvantages calling one over the other or is just about preferences?

No specific requirement except that stored procedures are called with parameters and return single or list of objects. Nothing fancy.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the most significant advantage of discussing with your colleague and settling on or the other rather than writing both into the code, is that you'll be being consistent. I find it intensely irritating to maintain projects by other people where multiple different ways of doing equivalent things are present, and I'm sure I'm not alone in being exasperated at massive style differences in long running dev projects where every new developer added to the team has wanted to pad his resumee in a different way

Comment: Agreed. This is why I wanted to know in the first place. I have no personal preferences but I thought I'd check to see if one was recommended over the other and why, but if it means I have to use ExecuteFunction to keep it consistent with what's already there, that's fine by me. :)

Comment: There isn't a lot of commentary about this, it seems but my take is that ObjectContext seems to be the lower level part of the framework and DbContext sits at a higher level of abstraction. I'd probably use whichever was most apt considering the rest of the data access strategy in the project/solution, but equally I often promote pushing up to higher level abstractions in most cases, i.e. "use an ORM rather than a DataReader", so I'd say "Use DbContext". Opinion though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObjectContext is the foundational API in EF4 - EF6 . The newer DbContext API was layered on top of the ObjectContext API when it was introduced EF 4.1.

When EF was re-written to make EF Core, the DbContext API became the main/only API and ObjectContext was not brought forward.

So, where ether API will work well enough, you should probably favor the DbContext API for eventual compatibility with EF Core.